# Fade between pages using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

I'm trying to add a transition effect to my site with Jquery.
Everything was working, but suddenly the site started flickering one time before the fade in effect... I add a `display:none` and it was solved. But if visitors have JavaScript disabled, they won’t be able to view the site.
I've already add it as a script but it doesn't work... Any ideas?
Here is my fade code:

```
<!--transition-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("body").css("display", "none");
            $("img").css("display", "none");

            $("body").fadeIn(2000);
            $("img").fadeIn(2000);

            $("a.link").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
            $("img").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);   
        });

        function redirectPage() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You should give the display:none to the elements in the stylesheet. As you have it now, the elements will be visible, then will hide only when the jquery starts loading

Comment: @Cláudio Barreira adding the display:none to the stylesheet will however prevent a graceful fallback for people with Javascript disabled as far as I understood the Question.

Comment: How about doing the fade in with CSS3 (which will fix your problem with JS disabled) and then doing the fadeout with the jQuery.

Comment: @CláudioBarreira The only problem is if visitors have JavaScript disabled, they won’t be able to view the site.

Comment: @EddSmith I did that whit the code from Ahs N answer and it works perfectly! Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can perform the fade in transition using CSS only, like so:

```
body {
    animation: myfadeInAnimation 2s;
}
div {
    width: 300px;
}
@keyframe myfadeInAnimation {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfadeInAnimation {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q3gL6y1t/)

As for the fade out effect, if the browser will not be running javascript, you will have no means of detecting the window unload and trigger an effect for it...

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Is it compatible with all the browsers?

Comment: Yes, the animation property is supported by most major browsers :)

Answer (score 1):

**For javascript disabled**  :   You can add this to your page,so user wont be able to see anything rather than a blank page and a useful message

```
<noscript>
         Javascript is not enabled on browser and require this to be enabled to function properly.
         Here are the <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">
         instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser</a>.
         <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.enable-javascript.com/">-->
          <style type="text/css">
             div.container { display:none;}
          </style>
 </noscript>
```

> assuming every thing is inside your container

Comment: I've already thought of adding that, but the website is for my clients. So I prefer a solution that doesn't mean a part of them not seeing the site right away...<br>Thanks anyway, i'll try other options, if they don't work, i'll have to go whit this...