# How to I fade background colors on load?

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a project, and I had an idea: it would be cool if I made the redirection to a page seem seamless, by fading the background color: Rebecca Purple, to #666 (grayish color).

Seems like a very weird idea, right? I would like the transition to be 1.5 seconds, and use JavaScript to control the color fading, transition time, etc.

The only problem is since my idea is weird, there isn't a tutorial available.

Comment: You [could also use CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138216/fade-between-pages-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks. I will edit the code to make it change the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you change class with JavaScript using onready event binding and delay the transition with css:

```
<div id="test" class="mainstyle style1">
  <p>
    hello
  </p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.style1{background-color: white;}
.style2{background-color:blue;}
.mainstyle{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition-delay:2s; 
    width:250px;}
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$(function() {
 $('#test').addClass('style2');
     $('#test').removeClass('style1'); 
});
```

[See the JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rqcx1hk/1/)

have fun!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.loaded').css('background','red').css('color','blue');
});
```

```css
.loaded {
  transition: 1.5s;
  color: black;
  background: yellow;
}
Try this! =)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loaded">Food!</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you may try the HSL colorspace, it produces very nice and natural looking gradients.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.